# Removing line breaks using Docs GAS

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, escaping, google-docs

I want to remove all newlines with spaces using google apps script for Docs

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody().editAsText();
body.replaceText("\\t", " "); //works properly for tabs
body.replaceText("\\n", " "); //doesnt work
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern-replacement

Any suggestions.?

Comment: Try `body.replaceText("[\n\r]+", " ");` or `body.replaceText("\\v", " "); `

Comment: I tried but not replacing `var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
        var body = doc.getBody().editAsText();
        body.replaceText("\\v", " "); `

Comment: What about `"[\n\r]+"`?

Comment: It would help more if you shared the document.

Comment: You may use https://sites.google.com/site/removelinebreaks/

Comment: Thank you Wiktor.

Comment: Actually, it is still a mystery to me how we can merge paragraphs into 1.

Comment: Does your document only contain paragraphs? Try `var pars = body.getParagraphs(); for( var j = 0; j < pars.length; ++j ) { try { pars[j].merge(); } catch  (e) {} }`. Or even without `try-catch` - `var pars = body.getParagraphs(); for( var j = 1; j < pars.length; ++j ) { pars[j].merge(); }`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `body.replaceText` does not allow replacements of what is between paragraphs (the paragraph breaks).

You need to somehow merge all paragraphs into 1 paragraph. You may do it roughly with the following code:

```
function mergePars() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var pars = body.getParagraphs();
  for( var j = 0; j < pars.length; ++j ) {
    try {
        pars[j].merge();
    } 
    catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e); // It will log "Exception: Element must be preceded by an element of the same type."
    }
  }
}
```

You may get rid of the try-catch if you get the number of all children in the document (with `.getNumChildren()`) and then loop through the items checking their `DocumentApp.ElementType`, and if the previous node was of type `DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH`, apply `.merge()`.